# In cakephp, How to retrieve linked table information

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cakePHP, and I have this problem :

Using the blog and bookmarkers tutorials, I have made an app to manage articles and users. I have linked my article table with the users' one, with user_id. When I get my article, I have the user_id who created it. But, I would like to retrieve the user's name instead of only the id.

I read that question [How to retrieve information when linking models through a table in CakePHP 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405078/how-to-retrieve-information-when-linking-models-through-a-table-in-cakephp-3-0) but I didn't understood how to make this on my own project.

This is my 'index' function in the ArticlesController (where I want the information to be displayed) :

```
/**
 * Index method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ];
    $articles = $this->paginate($this->Articles);


    $this->set(compact('articles'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['articles']);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your /Articles/index.ctp:

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <!-- HTML code here -->
    <?= h($article->users->name) ?> 
    <!-- HTML code here -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```